# How can I sort PHP globs by a variable within its elements?

Tags: php, sorting, glob

I have a glob of files within a certain directory. These files are PHP files with variable definitions. In these files are a custom 'date' variable. These dates do not match up with when the PHP file was created, but rather an otherwise arbitrary date. I am unsure of how to sort the glob based on those variables.

So far I have been unable to create a successful compare function or use `ksort` or similar functions to sort the glob based on variables within it.

The content of a standard item found by the glob will appear like this:

```php
<?php
$title = 'Example Title';
$info = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.';
$time = mktime(22,19,46,10,14,2019); //THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO SORT BY
$datestring = date("d F, Y H:i",$time);
?>
```

I would assume I should be able to sort given a variable from each element of the glob (for example the 'time' variable of each file in the glob) but I have been unable to find a sort function to allow this. Any sort I have found have sorted keys within an array, but these files are not arrays themselves so they have been incompatible.

Comment: A list of filenames will do you no good when you'll actually have to read the files and extract a convoluted expression. At this point it's perhaps time to realize that a database would have made sense.

Comment: I have been able to pull information from the files elsewhere in a foreach loop (e.g. `$files = glob("*.php"); foreach($files as $item){echo $item.$time;}`), but not sort the files in that list based on those variables. I am new to PHP so I am not aware of the difference of my files and a 'database'.

Comment: Addendum: My foreach loop has `include_once($item)` from which I reference the variables just by typing in the variable name (e.g. `$time` instead of `$item.$time`). This may be what I should focus on in the sort instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the $time variable from each file. You must therefore include every file in the loop with include, include_once is wrong here.

```
$files = glob("yourpath/*.php");
$array = array();
foreach($files as $file){
  include $file;
  $array[$time] = $file;
}
ksort($array);
```

Note:

This simple variant with ksort only works if different $time information is in each file.

Maybe it's better

```
$files = glob("yourpath/*.php");
$array = array();
foreach($files as $key => $file){
  include $file;
  $array[$file] = $time;
}
asort($array);
```

Comment: I suppose a typical sort function wouldn't work for my purposes due to the need of the `$time` variable?

Comment: It works like this. The condition is that in each file $time is also provided in the global scope. Try it yourself.

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve with it. If you want to create something similar to your own version control system, it is better to make the sorting information as special comments and get the contents of the php file with file_get_contents ().

Comment: My comment was more inquiring about this solution vs a traditional "compare" function that would get used in say `usort`. Though you solution does indeed work for my purpose, I am just curious to differences and advantages/disadvantages between the two methods.